# Gears Of War 3 Beta Rewards

Tags: achievements, gears-of-war-3

I heard that their are some achievments and challenges within the Gears of War 3 beta, could someone tell me what they are and what they require? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://m.ign.com/articles/1153613

It looks like there are unlockables like weapons and medals. I don't see achievements. The link above has a list of all the unlockables. Unlockables will carry over to the release version.